# How to integrate Tierion Hash API?

Tags: php, integration

I want to integrate Tierion Hash API with PHP, but I'm beginner and I don't kwon how to start...

In documentation, there is thisto begin: 
[image]

But I don't understand, how can I do the POST request? where can I write this ?
 `{
"username":"xxxxx","password":"xxxx"}`

}

Comment: you're probably best using Guzzle for API interactions

Comment: @MarkTwigg, can you send me an exemple to use it?

Comment: take a look at the documentation of guzzle it has some really detailed examples and well commented

Comment: @MarkTwigg, Ok, thank a lot !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tom from [Tierion](https://www.tierion.com) here. With the HashAPI, you need to first submit your account credentials to get a temporary access token. That access token is what you will submit with your POST request of your hash to the HashAPI, authenticating the the submission. I'll go over a few main requests with the Hash API and CURL-less PHP implementations:

---

**1) Getting your access token & refresh token via the /token/ endpoint, by submitting your credentials as parameters.**

First, you must submit your username and password as request parameters to our /token/ endpoint to get your access token. Your credentials are sent as parameters, not as request headers.

Code:

```
// Specify your request URL and the parameters you need to send.
$url = 'https://hashapi.tierion.com/v1/auth/token';
$data = array('username' => '_YOUR_USERNAME_', 'password' => '_YOUR_PASSWORD_');

// Use the "HTTP" key even if you're making an HTTPS request.
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

// Create and submit the HTTP request.
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check for a failed request, handle error according. 
    if ($response === FALSE) { 
        // Handle error
    }

// $response now holds your authorization token, expiration time, and refresh token. 
var_dump($response);
```

Sample Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyB9eXAiOiJKV1QiLDJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ8.eyJpZCI6IjU2ZyyiYzFhNWY5Yjg1MjMyZmRjYWRhNyIsInJsbiI6MjBwMCwicmxpIjoicyIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUtImlhdCI6MTQ2MTI0NzE2NSwiZXhwIjoxNDYxMjUwNzY1LCJqdGkiOiI1MDUyYmFlZDhkNTM5NjcyNDNiMjkzN2RjNjRjNTcyOTJmNTQwZDZhIn0.KNiG-QHdeaH1jVLJpx0ykov8Kk7ogts69k5OhDkgFVM",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "ec71236f77ebd665210912ae8891aa08ee8ec3e4"
}
```

---

**2) Getting an updated access token via the /refresh/ endpoint, by submitting your refresh token as a parameters.**

Your access token is valid for one hour, before it will need to be refreshed. You need to submit your refresh token you received with your authorization token to our /refresh/ endpoint. You'll get a new authorization token which will be valid for another hour Your access token is sent as a parameters, not a request header.

Code:

```
// Specify your request URL and the parameters you need to send.
$url = 'https://hashapi.tierion.com/v1/auth/refresh';
$data = array('refreshToken' => '_YOUR_VALID_REFRESH_TOKEN_');

// Use the "HTTP" key even if you're making an HTTPS request.
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

// Create and submit the HTTP request.
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check for a failed request, handle error according. 
    if ($response === FALSE) { 
        // Handle error
    }

// $response now holds your NEW authorization token, expiration time, and refresh token. 
var_dump($response);
```

Sample Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyoJAxeiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiIUJzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU2ZWRiYzFhNWY5Yjg1jMjyZmRjYWRhNyIsInJsbiI6MjAwMCwicmxpIjoicyIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTQ2MTI0Nzk5NCwiZXhwIjoxNDYxMjUxNTk0LJCqdGkiOiIyM2M5NjVjMTYwNzM3NWZlMzQ0MWFiNDFjZTZjM2JkODkzODYxNWRiIn0.qFKIpT5q4K0u1P8_jwUsQkxxcCGu3uGsQKi33c-1gEM",
  "expires_in": 3600,                                 
  "refresh_token": "ec32176f77ebd556210912ae8891aa08ff8ec3e4"
}
```

---

**3) Submitting your hash to the Hash API with your authorization token as a header in the request.**

Now that you have your access token, you can submit hashes to the Hash API. You need to make a request with your hash as a request parameter, and your authorization token as a request header.

Code:

```
// Specify your request URL and the parameters you need to send.
$url = 'https://hashapi.tierion.com/v1/hashitems';
$data = array('hash' => '_YOUR_SHA256_HASH_');

// Use the "HTTP" key even if you're making an HTTPS request.
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer _YOUR_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN_",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

// Create and submit the HTTP request.
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check for a failed request, handle error according. 
    if ($response === FALSE) { 
        // Handle error
    }

// $response now holds your blockchain receipt ID and timestamp.
var_dump($response);
```

Sample Response:

```
{
  "receiptId": "571694dd6b5c7b711861ea67",
  "timestamp": 1461097693
}
```

---

**4) Receive the corresponding blockchain receipt with a receiptId.**

After you send a hash, you'll receive a receiptId. This Id is a unique pointer within the Tierion system to your blockchain receipt. This Id does not correlate to the blockchain itself, the receipt does. To obtain the receipt, you send the receiptId to our /receipts/ endpoint.

You append the receiptId to the end of the request URL, rather than sending it through a request parameter.

Code:

```
// Specify your request URL and the parameters you need to send.
$url = 'https://hashapi.tierion.com/v1/receipts' + _YOUR_RECEIPT_ID_;

// Use the "HTTP" key even if you're making an HTTPS request.
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer _YOUR_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN_",
        'method'  => 'POST',
    )
);

// Create and submit the HTTP request.
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Check for a failed request, handle error according. 
    if ($response === FALSE) { 
        // Handle error
    }

// $response now holds your blockchain receipt. 
var_dump($response);
```

Sample Response:

```
  {
  "receipt": "{\"@context\":\"https://w3id.org/chainpoint/v2\",\"type\":\"ChainpointSHA256v2\",\"targetHash\":\"a83a2c5c11a2bc814d0b1dca0a385d71a1f4d662b4e31335ba7562c56cce15b1\",\"merkleRoot\":\"2d21167d2f2f73e309d5ac00ab9faaf8b530478c5b64dcd5755511c8a3eccfa3\",\"proof\":[{\"left\":\"7c6e3b0159f1359d0f9f5a3b923011b7466bdf1423317ca09121b5dc61ad1836\"},{\"right\":\"541c5ae04e83c2880296818978511893ba1b00f1515162cd865f25da54f636d0\"},{\"right\":\"67b7ced55a4db4bb0fbaf2036901888a08ab7d8126556431258017652cf62092\"}],\"anchors\":[{\"type\":\"BTCOpReturn\",\"sourceId\":\"33884d525ca1cc54313fa2f27be4cf3442b35314866851cc7fc5ec3973d80250\"}]}"
}
```

---

If you have any further questions, feel free to reach out to our team at **team@tierion.com** or check out our [Hash API documentation](https://tierion.com/docs/hashapi). The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) provides more information about PHP HTTP requests.

Comment: How can I do to find this transaction into blockchain? For exemple I have a receipId = "57bb2143c7a7eb032af78b25", but when I tap this into search bar on blockchain.info there is this error : Unrecognized search pattern

Comment: I have added a fourth point to the above answer regarding obtaining your receipt. You must send the receiptId to our /receipt/ endpoint to get the full blockchain receipt, which contains the source ID that you can then look up on Blockchain.info.

Comment: It's working!!! thank a lot!!! I just have a last question, after I found the transaction on blockcahin.info, where can I find the hash I inserted into transaction?

Comment: for example, I have this sourceId : a0241fa01a2c8fda2592127026985a5f6290b7b194323bb1e87fe8f43d236a11

Comment: The sourceId value is stored in the OP_RETURN output value. When viewing a transaction on blockchain.info, you will see a link to 'show scripts'. When you click on that, input and output scripts will be displayed at the bottom of the page. Among the output scripts, you will see the label 'OP_RETURN'. The sourceId will be immediately to the right of this label. You may also consider using blocktrail.com instead, at it will display all the information you need about the transaction without having to unhide the OP_RETURN data.

Comment: @TomKysar - is there a .net sdk for chainpoint node api?  Or any sample developed for .net application that uses chainpoint Node API?